# Console Text game: Vertical Scroller collision problems

Tags: c++, game-loop, console

Alright so i'm making a **vertical side scroller where you are an '8' character traveling downward while avoiding my randomly generated walls (*the "generation" function*) on the left and right sides of the screen, and made of 'X's. you can collide with this wall 4 times before losing.**

When you collide with the wall you can no longer move, and are basically are stuck in that column of the screen until you pop out into an open space, known as a ' ' (space) character. You lose *one life* for each **INITIAL** collision with the X wall, and do not lose another until you have popped out and been freed from it.

As an added touch i have made it so after you collide while traveling down the randomly generated map (or rather as the walls move uppward while your character stays put) the X chars you've collided with are deleted. However I am having trouble getting the INITIAL COLLISION with the wall to be detected correctly. the result is the playe incorrectly losing 4 lives after hitting 1 wall and traveling throug it. This is due to some odd reason for the "numb_collisions", which is used to count how many collisions have occured since initial collision (if it's 0 it means it *IS* the **initial collision occuring= -1 shield**), keeps getting reset to 0. The detect_collision function seems to having some sort of problems as the returned value is allowing the if statement to pretend there is no collision, reseting "numb_coll" to 0 and screwing the lives/shields up. **All this nonsense is located at the bottom of the main function**

Finally the **Screen.Insert()** *function and others like it simply saves the data into a vector  which represents the console window. It is later used to print the "screen" to the console at a set rate (long double speed), as seen in the for loop after the map drawings in the main function *

not Finally.. but i believe that te numb_coll problem has something to do with the time and framrate. When running full speed i quickly die upon entering a wall as numb_coll doesn't change or gets changed back to 0 somehow. When putting a stop in my msVS++ it works perfectly... and when holding F5 (shortcut for "continue") it partly works but numb_coll still gets set to 0 every 3 or 4 X's down in the wall...

I hope this is enough explination, Thanks for any Help, and 
**LOOK AT PREVIOUS POST ABOUT COLLISION DETECTION FOR MORE SPECIFIC FUNCTION PROBLEMS**
otherwise, heres all the code: Thanks again!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> // or "ctime"
#include <stdio.h> // for 
#include <cstdlib> 
// Windows stuff
#include <Windows.h> // GOD DAMMNIT WINDOWS WHY????
#include <conio.h>
// Ncurses
#include<curses.h>
// STL stuff
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
//String/Int conversion
#include <sstream>
// gives access to rand function
#include <cstdlib>
//gives access to time functions
#include <ctime>

// mySTOPWATCH   i think i'm gonna cry.... =')
#include <myStopwatch.h> // for keeping times
#include <myMath.h>      // numb_digits() and digit_val();
using namespace std;
enum{ NUMB_LINES= 24, SEC= 1000};                   // time stuff
enum{TIME= 345, HEALTH = 346, MAP= 247};    // for Refresh() command
enum{NONE= 256};                                    // for Refresh() transition
enum{NEW = 590, OLD = 591};                         // for the old/new screen command

// Some nCurses setup
 int r = 0,
     c = 0; // current row and column (upper-left is (0,0))
 const int nrows = 56, // number of rows in window
           ncols = 79; // number of columns in window
// Timer Setup
 Stopwatch myStopwatch(3, START);

 ///////////////////////////        RandNumb()  ///////////////////////////////////////
int RandNumb(int scope){
    srand(GetTickCount());
    return rand() % scope;};
//////////////////////////      GeneratePathStart() ///////////////////////////////
void GeneratePathStart(vector<string>& buff){
    int wall= RandNumb(80)/2, 
        space = (RandNumb(75)/2)+5,
        wall2= 80- (wall+space);
    buff.push_back("");
    for(;wall> 0; wall--){
        buff[0].push_back('X');}
    for(;space> 0; space--){
        buff[0].push_back(' ');}
    for(; wall2 > 0; wall2--){
        buff[0].push_back('X');}
    };

//////////////////////////      GeneratePath()  ////////////////////////////////////
void GeneratePath( vector<string>& buff){// the buff is the seed  too
    int wall= RandNumb(80)/2, 
        space = (RandNumb(75)/2)+5,
        wall2= 80-(space+wall);
    int swall= 0;
        for(char i= '0'; i!= ' ';swall++)
            i= buff[buff.size()-1][swall+1];
    int sspace= 0; int I= swall+1;
        for(char i= '0'; i!= 'X';sspace++, I++)
            i= buff[buff.size()-1][I];
    int swall2 = 80-(sspace+swall);

    // now the actual generation
    int cwall= wall-swall; 
    int cspace= space-sspace; 
    int cwall2= wall2-swall2;
    for(;cwall!= 0 || cspace!= 0 /*|| cwall2 != 0*/;){
            buff.push_back("");
//cwall
            if(cwall!= 0){
                if(cwall>0){
                    swall++;
                    cwall--;}
                else{ // cwall is negative
                    swall--;
                    cwall++;}}
            for(int w= 0; w <swall; w++)
                buff[buff.size()-1].push_back('X');
// cspace
            if(cspace!= 0){
                if(cspace>0){
                    sspace++;
                    cspace--;}
                else{ // cspace is negative
                    sspace--;
                    cspace++;}}
            for(int s= 0; s <sspace; s++)
                buff[buff.size()-1].push_back(' ');
// cwall2
            //if(cwall2!= 0){               
            //  if(cwall2>0){
            //      wall2++;
            //      cwall2--;}
            //  else{ // cspace is negative
            //      wall2--;
            //      cwall2++;}}
            for(int w2= 0; w2 <80- (swall+sspace); w2++)
                buff[buff.size()-1].push_back('X');
    }}// end of function

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////    Sprite Class    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Sprite
{

private:
    string name;
    char symbol;
    float shield;
    int location[2];
    bool alive;

public:
///////////////////// Get and SET all the privates  ///////
    Sprite(){};
    Sprite(string a_name, char a_symbol, float a_health){
        name = a_name;
        symbol = a_symbol;
        shield = a_health;};

    char get_symbol() {return symbol;};
    void set_symbol(char sym) {symbol = sym;};

    float get_shield() {return shield;};
    void set_shield(float numb) {shield = numb;};
    void add_shield (float numb) {shield += numb;};
    void destroy_shield() {shield--; if(shield<0) alive= false;}

    string get_name() {return name;};
    string set_name(string aName) {name = aName;};

    int* get_location(){return location;};
    void set_location(int X, int Y) {
        location[0] = X;
        location[1] = Y;};

    bool Alive() {return alive;};
    void SetLife(bool f) {alive= f;};

////////////////////////////////    Move    ////////////
    bool move(int X, int Y) {
                location[0] += X;
                location[1] += Y;
                return true;};
};// end of sprite


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////   Player Class    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Player : public Sprite
{
public:
    Player(string name,int X, int Y, float health){
        set_symbol('8');
        set_name(name);
        set_location(X,Y);
        set_shield(100);};
private:
    // none?

};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////      Map class   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Map
{
private:
///////////////////////////////////////////     Map Variables ///////////////
    string name;
    vector <string> contents;
    vector <string> save;

public:
    Map(){};
    Map(string* lines, int i, string name= "map"){name = name;
                                           contents.resize(56);
                                           Insert(lines, i);};
    ~Map(){};

///////////////////////////////////////////     generate    ////////////////////
    void generate(){GeneratePath(contents);};
///////////////////////////////////////////     Return()    ////////////////////
    string Name()               {return name;};
    vector <string> Contents()  {return contents;};
    string Contents(int Y)      {return contents[Y];};
    char Contents(int Y, int X) {return contents[Y][X];};
    vector <string> Save()      {return save;};
    int size()                  {return contents.size();};

///////////////////////////////////////////     Insert()    ////////////////////
            //  string* to an array of 24 strings;
    void Insert(string* lines, int i)            
    {contents.assign(lines, lines+i);}; //insert lines 1-24

    void Insert(string astring, int Y)   {contents[Y] = astring;};

    void Insert(char achar, int X, int Y){contents[Y][X] = achar;};

    void Saveline(string line)           {save.push_back(line);}; 
};

/////////////////////////   SCREEN CLASS        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Screen
{
private:
///////////////////////////////////////////     Screen Variables ///////////////
    string _name;
    vector <string> new_map;
    vector <string> old_map;
    vector <Sprite*> sprites_p;

public:
    Screen(string name){_name = name;
                        new_map.resize(nrows);
                        old_map.resize(nrows);};
    ~Screen(){};

////////////////////////////////////////////    Get contents    ///////////////////////////
    vector <string> get_contents(int comm= NEW)              {switch(comm){ case NEW: return new_map; break;
                                                                            case OLD: return old_map; break;}};
    string get_contents         (int Y, int comm= NEW)       {switch(comm){ case NEW: return new_map[Y]; break;
                                                                            case OLD: return old_map[Y]; break;}};
    char get_contents           (int X, int Y, int comm= NEW){switch(comm){ case NEW: return new_map[Y][X]; break;
                                                                            case OLD: return old_map[Y][X]; break;}};

////////////////////////////////////////////    Refresh     ///////////////////////////
void Refresh(int command= ALL, int transition= NONE)
{
    //old_map = new_map;    // update the old map
    for(int r= 0; r< nrows; r++){ move(r,0); 
                                  addstr((char*)new_map[r].c_str());}                   // make sure this works later
    // Insert Time 
    if(command== ALL || command== TIME){
    enum{ time_loc_y= 22, 
          time_loc_x= 38 };
    mvaddstr(time_loc_y, time_loc_x, myStopwatch.ClockTime().c_str());}

refresh();}; // end of function

///////////////////////////////////////////     Insert  ////////////////////////
                                                            /////////////////// Map
    void Insert(Map& map, int y1, int y2)   {for ( int mc = y1, nm= 0; mc< map.size() && mc< y2; mc++, nm++){
                                                new_map[nm] = map.Contents(mc);}
    };
                                                            /////////////////// string
    void Insert(string astring, int Y)      {new_map[Y] = astring;};
                                                            ///////////////////// char
    void Insert(char achar, int X, int Y)   {new_map[Y][X] = achar;};
                                                            ////////////////////  sprite
    void Insert(Sprite& sprite)         {new_map[sprite.get_location()[1]][sprite.get_location()[0]] = sprite.get_symbol();
                                         sprites_p.push_back(&sprite);};    // save a pointer to the sprite

///////////////////////////////////////////     Collision Detection ///////////
    bool check_collision(Sprite& sprite,int X, int Y, char& buff) 
    {
    ////////////////////// check whats already there /////
        char newloc = new_map[sprite.get_location()[1]+Y]
                             [sprite.get_location()[0]+X];
        if(newloc == '|' || newloc == '/' || newloc == '_' || newloc == '=' || newloc == 'X' || newloc == '-' || newloc == 'x' ) {
            buff = newloc;
            sprite.destroy_shield();
            return true;}

        else return false;
    };
};


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////   MAIN    ////////////////////////////////////  MAIN  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
cout << "Maximize the screen for optimum experience!... type ok when done" << endl;
char response; cin >> response;

    WINDOW *wnd;
 wnd = initscr(); // curses call to initialize window and curses mode
 //cbreak(); // curses call to set no waiting for Enter key
 noecho(); // curses call to set no echoing
 //curs_set(a number); (0 = invisible, 1 = normal, 2 = very visible)
 int row,col; getmaxyx(stdscr,row,col);     /* get the number of rows and columns */
 clear(); // curses call to clear screen, send cursor to position (0,0)

 Screen theScreen("ascreen");

        string splashScreen[24] = {    // HERE"S THE SPLASH !
//                    1        2        3       4        5         6        7        8        
//                         123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789
//               0123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789         1234567
/* 0 */         "________________________________________________________________________________", 
/* 1 */         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",  
/* 2 */         "|XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 3 */         "|XXXXXX  /  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     xXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXx  xXXXXXXx  xXXX|", 
/* 4 */         "|XXXXX  /0}  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXx  XXXXXXx /X xXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX    XXX|", 
/* 5 */         "|XXXX  /000}  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXXXXx  XXXXX  /X  XXXXXXXX  /X  XXXX  /X  XX|", 
/* 6 */         "|XXX           XXXXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXXXXXxx XXXX  /XXX  XXXXXXX /XX  XXXX  |X  XX|", 
/* 7 */         "|XX   /XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXX   /XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  /XXX  XXXXXX  |XXX  XX   /X  xX|", 
/* 8 */         "|X   /XXXXXXXX   X*X*X*XXX  /XXXXx        xXX          XXXXX  |XXX      /XXX  X|", 
/* 9 */         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXX   XX  /XXXXX  XXXX   |XXXX    /XXXX  X|", 
/* 10 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXX    Xx /XXXXXXX xXXX   |XXXXx  /XXXX   X|", 
/* 11*/         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX            XXXx /XXXXXXX xXX     XXXXXxxXXXX    x|", 
/* 12 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 13 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXXX|", 
/* 14 */        "|XXX  XXxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                  XXX|", 
/* 15 */        "|XXX  XXXx  XX/  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_____XX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 16 */        "|XXX    XXX  /  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 17 */        "|XXX /0] XX/  XXXXx      xXX  XXXXXXXXXXX    xXXX    xXXXX                 xXXX|", 
/* 18 */        "|XXX    XX/  XXXXX  XXXXXXXX    xXXX  XXX  XXXXXX  XXXXXXX                 xXXX|", 
/* 19 */        "|XXXXXXXX  XXXXXXX  XXx  xXX  XXXXXX  XXX    xXXX    xXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 20 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXX  XX  XXXXXX  XXX  XXXXXX  XXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 21 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx      xXXxxXXXXXXxxXXX xXXXXXX xXXXXXXX                  XXX|", 
/* 22 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXX|", 
/* 23 */        "|______________________________________________________________________________|",};

    string _lines_[56] = {   
//                    1        2        3       4        5         6        7        8        
//                         123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789
//               0123456789         123456789         123456789         123456789         1234567
/* 0 */         "________________________________________________________________________________", 
/* 1 */         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",  
/* 2 */         "|XXXXXXXX                    XXXXXXXXXXXXX              XXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 3 */         "|XXXXX                 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 4 */         "|XXXX      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 5 */         "|XXX      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 6 */         "|XX       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 7 */         "|XX       XXXXXXXX           XXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 8 */         "|XXX       XXXXXXXXXX         XXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 9 */         "|XXXX        XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 10 */        "|XXXXX        XXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 11 */        "|XXXXXXX        XXXXXXXXX     XXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 12 */        "|XXXXXXXX        XXXXXXX      XXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   XXXXXXXX|",
/* 13 */        "|XXXXXXXXXX       XXXXX       XXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXX___XXXXXXXX|",
/* 14 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXX                XXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXxxxXXXXXXXX|",
/* 15 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXX              XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXXXx   xXXXXXXX|",
/* 16 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX              XXXXXXXXXXXx   xXXXXXXX|",
/* 17 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
/* 18 */        "|    MOVE USING 'WASD' |=|  avoid the walls |=|  SURVIVE!!  |=|  press 'O' quit|",
/* 19 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
/* 20 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|",
/* 21 */        "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",
/* 22 */        "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",
/* 23 */        "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",
/* 0 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 1 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|",  
/* 2 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 3 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 4 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 5 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 6 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 7 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 8 */         "|XXX                                                                        XXX|", 
/* 9 */         "|XXXX                                                                      XXXX|", 
/* 10 */        "|XXXXX                                                                    XXXXX|", 
/* 11*/         "|XXXXXX                                                                  XXXXXX|", 
/* 12 */        "|XXXXXXX                                                                XXXXXXX|", 
/* 13 */        "|XXXXXXXX                                                              XXXXXXXX|", 
/* 14 */        "|XXXXXXXXX                                                            XXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 15 */        "|XXXXXXXXXX                                                          XXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 16 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXX                                                        XXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 17 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXX                                                        XXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 18 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXX                                                      XXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 19 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXX                                                      XXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 20 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 21 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 22 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 23 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|"
/* 24 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 25 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 26 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 27 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 28 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 29 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                              XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 30 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 31*/         "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
/* 32 */        "|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|", 
};    

    //////////////////////////////////  Splash Screen   /////////////////////////////   
    Map splashScreen_map(splashScreen, 24);
    theScreen.Insert(splashScreen_map, 0, nrows);
    theScreen.Refresh(MAP);
    myStopwatch.Wait(3);
    myStopwatch.Restart();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Map L1(_lines_, nrows, "L1");
    theScreen.Insert(L1, 0, nrows);
    Sprite player("Player",'8', 5);   //(8, 12, 16);
    player.set_location(47, 22);

    ////////////////////// Check if new line is needed;
    double refreshes= 0;
    int newlines= 0;
    const double speed= .1;

    int numb_coll= 0;
    bool dead= false;
/////////////////////////   start of the for loop
    for (bool quit = false; quit != true && dead== false;)
    {   double newTime= myStopwatch.ElapsedTime()- refreshes;
        if(newTime >= speed){
            theScreen.Insert(L1, 0+newlines, nrows+newlines);
            refreshes+= speed;
            newlines++;
            if(L1.size()<= nrows+newlines+2)
                L1.generate();}
    /////////////////   Keypress    ///////////
    int xMove = 0;
    int yMove = 0;
    if (kbhit()){
        int key = getch(); 
        key = toupper(key); // makes whatever key uppercase

                        int stepSize = 1;
                        bool validPress = true;
        switch(key){
    // update health here............
        case 'W': yMove = -stepSize;break;
        case 'S': yMove = stepSize; break;
        case 'A': xMove = -stepSize;break;
        case 'D': xMove = stepSize; break;

        case 'P': getch();          break;
        case 'O': quit = true;

        default: validPress = false;}

        if(validPress == true){/*do something here or i might not need it.....*/}
        } /* end of if(kbhit())*/ 

        char coll; // the buffer for the collided char
        theScreen.check_collision(player, xMove, yMove, coll);
        if(coll== 'X'){ 
            if(player.Alive()== false){}
                // do something about it 
                // if there is life
            else{
                for(int I= 0; I< numb_coll && numb_coll< player.get_location()[1]; I++){
                    theScreen.Insert(' ',player.get_location()[0], player.get_location()[1]-(I+1));}
                if(numb_coll>0)
                    player.add_shield(1);
                numb_coll++;
                theScreen.Insert(player);}}
        else if(coll != 'X'){
            theScreen.Insert(' ', player.get_location()[0],player.get_location()[1]);// get rid of old player placing
            player.move(xMove, yMove);                                               // put in new charater placing
            theScreen.Insert(player);
            numb_coll= 0;}

    theScreen.Refresh();}// so refresh and restart the for loop
if(dead== true){
//  theScreen.Insert(a gameover map);
               }
endwin(); // curses call to restore the original window and leave
return 0;
}
```

Comment: since you already published your code, code you please provide your entire project files so that it'll make it easy to debug.

Comment: @Gajet What? That's completely and utterly stupid..it really is not difficult to look over code and see what it does.

Comment: and by the way where didi you find NCurses which works on visual studio?

Comment: @Gajet [pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) is good for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright i figured it out: i was "**colliding with myself**" as the check collision function saw my character sprite in the location it was checking, even if it was still in the wall... This happened in-between the map scrolling and changes.

Answer (score 2):

This code is a mess, but after a cursory glance I'm going to go out on a limb and say you probably want to check against the value of check_collision.  The char you pass by reference into the function is uninitialized (albeit probably zeroed out in debug builds) and you don't set it in the false case of the function, but you immediately check it afterwards.

Really what you need to do is attach a debugger to it and step through it to see what's going on.

Comment: Yeah I pretty much have NO idea on how to organize/plan my code... would you know of any good books/sites that could teach me?

Comment: alright i figured it out: i was "colliding with myself" as the check collision function saw my character sprite in the location it was checking, even if it was still in the wall...  Oops this was supposed to be an answer